# How to compile VC++ 2010 projects using Visual Studio 2012 and Windows SDK 7.1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2012

I have a lot of projects done with VS2010 in C++. Now we have switched to VS2012 but we want to continue building the projects with the VS2010 runtime (we need to support Windows XP).

To our understanding this could be possible using Windows SDK 7.1 as the VC compiler is there so we installed it. VS2012 recognized the SDK and now we have a `Platform Toolset` named `Windows7.1SDK`.

The problem comes when building the projects as some projects are returning a:

> error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741515.

Also, projects depending on the MFCs are failing too. MFCs aren't available with Windows SDK? Does this mean that we need to buy VS2010 licenses to install them on machines with VS2012 just to build using the VS2010 compiler?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the hell the downvote? This should be fixed asap in SO. If you donwvote, tell why, otherwise I cannot improve the question!

Comment: +1 for "If you donwvote, tell why"

Comment: I would like to use Windows SDK 7.1 with VS 2012 also, has anyone find a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's not possible at all, mainly because nothing but VS2010 is deploying the MFC libraries and we have a lot of projects using them.

We'll have to buy licenses for VS2010 and VS2012 :S

Comment: I would love to do that but obviously it's not an option. We're developing a 15 years old application :S

Comment: I don't know a lot about MFC, but it seems you can compile MFC with an Express edition, with some effort. Supposing it still applies with VS 2010 ... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30439/How-to-compile-MFC-code-in-Visual-C-Express

Answer (score 1):

I would try raise the msbuild verbosity level (it is in Tools->Options->Project and Solution-> MSBuild) and check out the command of CL.exe with full parameters. Then check if it is different from what you saw on VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

In fall Microsoft will release an update to support windows xp in visual studio 2012, you can read more in this MSDN blog:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/06/15/10320645.aspx