# Use VS2008 (v90) C++ toolset in VS2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2013

[MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff770576.aspx) explains how to use 2010 or 2012 toolsets in VS2013.

Does anyone know if there is also backwards support for the 2008 toolset? I am upgrading several projects from 2008 to 2013 but my team lead would like us to upgrade the project files initially but still target the same compiler/runtime as 2008.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use Visual Studio 2012 and compile with older platform toolset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453629/use-visual-studio-2012-and-compile-with-older-platform-toolset)

Comment: No, I reviewed that question before posting. The solution points to the link I referred to. The answer is in regards to vs2012 and only suggests that installing 2008 may work (which it doesnt). When selecting platform toolset under properties 2012 and 2010 are listed but not 2008.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The VS2008 install on its own doesn't properly setup the toolset directory/registry. This prevents later version of VS from locating the v90 tools.

If you install the VS2010 C++ compiler toolset it will include the v90 toolset as well. After doing this I am able to build in VS2013 with the VS2008 toolset. This can be done by installing VS2010 itself or installing the Windows 7.1 SDK which includes the 2010 toolsets (v90 and v100).

Reference:
[MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b99e1d00-c696-4258-83b8-c683ea744d6f/v90-not-%20showing-up-in-vc11-platform-toolset-even-though-vc9-is-installed?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

Answer (score 1):

I get the option to select VS 2008 (v90) as a Platform Toolset for my VC++ projects in VS 2013.  I did nothing special (other than VS 2008 was installed when I installed VS2013).

Comment: Hm. I have 2008, 2012, and 2013 installed but only see options to select either the 2012 or 2013 toolsets. Any advice?

Comment: No great ideas. You might try reinstalling VS 2013 (or maybe a repair install) to see if it picks up VS 2008 this time. Another option might be to try to add it manually using the information here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx (which is a blog article that the MSDN docs link to, so I guess it's official). I must say that the configuration of alternate toolsets looks to be incredibly complicated. The manual configuration would probably be much easier if you can find someone who has a working configuration that you can copy files from.