# Compiling in VS 2013 Using compiler tools v90 error

Tags: c++

I ran into a problem which everytime i try to compile just a test project with windows 2013 using v90 compiler tools, i get this error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Test Console App, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.targets(62,5): error : Required file "" is missing.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

It works fine if i compile it using VS 2008, but I feel more confortable with visual studio 2013 or 2012, Intellisence is much better, as well as the colors, etc...

I installed the windows 7.1 SDK, as well as the update pack with the 2010 Compiler tools. I have both VS 2008 and VS 2013, as well as all the C++ Redists.

I can't compile the projects I'm working on, since we have libs compiled with 2008 to which we don't have the sources to, giving us linker errors.

Thanks

Comment: `error : Required file "" is missing.` I think the project file has an error. Open it in a text editor and look at the xml.

Comment: The error comes up also when I started a new test project as you can see I did above.

Comment: I would still investigate the project file.

Comment: Okay, I will do so when I get home and come back with feedback

Comment: It may be that an environment variable is empty or something like that.

Comment: You are missing files, VS2010 must be installed as well.  Reference [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172319/use-vs2008-v90-c-toolset-in-vs2013).

Answer (score 2):

The answer was to have visual studio 2010 installed. Express worked nicely.
Just for other people with the same problem, here is what you do:

```
Install VS 2013/2012 depending on which one you want.
Install VS 2008 and 2010 ( can be express ).

If that doesnt pick up your compiler tools v90/v100 then just follow these instructions:
-Uninstall all C++ 2010 Redists if any, or SDK 7.1 won't install.
-Install Windows SDK 7.1 and then download the Windows C++ Compiler Tools 2010 update for the SDK.
-Install the C++ Redists again.
-Reboot.
```

-Enjoy! :P