# How can I get rid of these dll dependencies?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, dll, static-linking

I'm building a c++ application which uses OpenSSL and Curl static libraries with Visual Studio 2013. My problem is that I wanted to create a standalone executable which is compatible with older versions of windows so I've enabled /MT flag in my project options and also when I built both of the libraries. Then I used cygwin to see what dlls are needed and I saw some strange one.

```
api-ms-win-downlevel-user32-l1-1-0.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/api-ms-win-downlevel-user32-l1-1-0.dll (0x75ee0000)
api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l1-1-0.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l1-1-0.dll (0x75c50000)
api-ms-win-downlevel-version-l1-1-0.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/api-ms-win-downlevel-version-l1-1-0.dll (0x75c40000)
api-ms-win-downlevel-normaliz-l1-1-0.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/api-ms-win-downlevel-normaliz-l1-1-0.dll (0x75c30000)
api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l1-1-0.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l1-1-0.dll (0x75da0000)
```

I guess these are not included in the standard windows setup. 
I also tried to build with Visual Studio 2010 but they're still there.

How can I get rid of them?

Comment: How would you use WinAPI without linking to it somehow?

Comment: I looked up in google those DLLs and it says that those are part of the windows 8 and above. But my point is that I want my application to run on windows 7 without installing any packages. (Sorry for bad english, not my native)

Comment: Standard heisenberg, it is not your program that needs these DLLs, it is cygwin.  Biggest mistake you are making right now is not trying to run your program on win7.

Comment: I compile and run under win 7 and it works fine, but I'm afraid that on other computers it won't work properly.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15454139/5781248) quotes "To change the target platform toolset, you must have the associated version of Visual Studio or the Windows Platform SDK installed. "