# Visual Studio 2010 without IDE

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I've got a problem: I must edit a C++ program which cannot be compiled with the compiler included in VS2012, but it can only be done using VS2010. Now the problem is quite simple to explain: how can I install the 2010 compiler without its IDE, so I can use it in VS2012? I use VS2012 and it's only a waste of free hard drive space if I install the IDE, too.

Comment: As far as I know, the compiler is build in, and is not really available to install externally. Why are you only able to compile it in this comppiler? (Sorry for bad English)

Comment: Well I wouldn't go as far as to say you can't. My Qt targets my compiler from VS. How to do it is another question. One I can't answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You need to install VS2010(Express edition will do) and then select platform toolset v100 while editing your project from VS2012

Comment: @FrontBack: in conjunction with this answer. You may want to look at [C++ Native Multi-Targeting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx). It only needs the tool kits so you may be able to download express take that file out and delete it. Then follow the instructions in the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `cl.exe` of platform v100 from the [Windows SDK 7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/dlx/en-us/listdetailsview.aspx?FamilyID=6b6c21d2-2006-4afa-9702-529fa782d63b).

VS2012 should recognise it after you install, but I'm not sure whether it can actually compile successfully - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104502/how-to-compile-vc-2010-projects-using-visual-studio-2012-and-windows-sdk-7-1?rq=1) seems to indicate that it will not work.